# Convert MySQL Query to Django query

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm converting a FlaskApp to Django.  In my Flask App I was doing straight DB queries w/o an ORM like MySQLAlchemy.

I'm having trouble converting my count queries for use in Django.  Seems simple enought, but I'm missing something.

**OLD FUNCTION W/ QUERY**

```
def countClients(db, begin, end, type):
    c = db.cursor()
    query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM newclients WHERE method LIKE %s AND (enddate BETWEEN %s AND %s)"
    c.execute(query, (type, begin, end))
    output = int(c.fetchone()[0])
    return output
```

**NEW QUERY**

```
for year in range(2015, today.year):
    for month in range(1, 13):
        startdate = datetime.date(year, month, 1)
        enddate = last_day_of_month(startdate)
        try:
            Count14.append(
                newclients.objects.filter(method = 'Test Drive',
                                          enddate__range=(startdate, enddate)
                                          )
            ).count()
```

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

- Query without Try:Except

w/o the try except I get a traceback

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count'
```

- Adding a int() around the query

But the int function can't accept a queryset.

**NOTE**
I have used portions of these queries successfully, but these what I'm trying here is more complex than the others.

i.e.  This one works, but is simpler.

```
clients = newclients.objects.filter(method=method_query).filter(enddate__range=(begindate, enddate))
```

Comment: Should the `.count()` be on the `newclients.objects.filter(...)` result rather than the `Count14.append()` result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.count()` is in the wrong place. It needs to be after the second close parenthesis, not the third.

As it is, you are calling it on the result of `append`, which is always None.

Comment: ARGH!   Thank you.